# How can I use the linegoal package with LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, linegoal

It seems like `\linegoal` isn't working correctly with LuaTeX:

[image: LuaTeX output]

With pdfTeX the output is fine:

[image: pdfTeX output]

Is there a way get `\linegoal` working with lualatex? Or is there an alternative?

MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{linegoal}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    Hello \fbox{\parbox{\linegoal}{World}}

    \blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pkg `linegoal` needs an update. This fixes the issue for `luatex`:

```
\let\pdfsavepos\savepos
\let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos
\let\pdflastypos\lastypos

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{linegoal}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    Hello \fbox{\parbox{\linegoal}{World}}

    \blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could `\RequirePackage{luatex85}`

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, of course. Just wanted to point out the specific items in `linegoal` that need to be fixed.