# Determine the length of the rest of a math display line for multlined

Tags: math-mode, calculations, mathtools, lengths

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
  \text{beginning}\land
  \begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth]
   (\text{extremely long and boring junk occupying lots of space})\\\relax
   [\text{a variable substitution in brackets}]
 \end{multlined}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output]

What to say instead of the argument `\linewidth` such that the second math line (a substitution in the brackets) is right-aligned to the right text margin instead of going beyond it? I.e., how do we compute "the length of the rest of the line till the right margin"?

(As you might imagine, this is an oversimplified version of a larger real-life example, so for this very MWE, please don't suggest using `multline*` instead because in my larger example, this stuff is nested inside another block math environment.)

Comment: Have you tried `\linegoal` from the [linegoal package](https://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal?lang=en)? (Requires multiple compilations to get right.)

Comment: Use of `[\linewidth]` is optional when you like to manually determine width of `multilined` part of equation. If you drop it,  you will left this care to LaTeX and result in your case will be fine.

Comment: @frabjous `\linegoal` works like a charm for this MWE for `pdflatex` and `xelatex` only. Not so for `lualatex`.

Comment: @Zarko Dropping `[\linewidth]` works for this very MWE indeed, but in general (and in my larger, non-minimal example I've not shown), it may produce suboptimal results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the `linegoal` package (not that it's bug-free, but for a single application it should be OK).

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[
  \text{beginning}\land
  \begin{multlined}[t][\linegoal]
   (\text{extremely long and boring junk occupying lots of space})\\\relax
   [\text{a variable substitution in brackets}]
 \end{multlined}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\[
  \text{beginning}\land
  \begin{multlined}[t][0.95\linegoal]
   (\text{extremely long and boring junk occupying lots of space})\\\relax
   [\text{a variable substitution in brackets}]
 \end{multlined}
\]
\lipsum[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

In the second case I reduced the desired width in order to avoid compression of space around `\land` and to still get visible centering (but not wasting too much space).

[image]

Comment: For me, compiling with `lualatex` produces the bracketed stuff going into the margin: https://i.imgur.com/YL5w8kd.png .

Comment: @AlbertNash See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525357/4427

Answer (score 2):

You place the `multilined` environment in the middle of the line, so, in order to not let it overlap the right margin, it should be shorter than `\linewidth` by the part you add before it.

Since `mathtools` loads the `calc` package, you could make use of the macro `\widthof` that gets you the width of arbitrary text. Using this, you can subtract from `\linewidth` the width if the stuff you add before the `multilined` environment (the drawback admittedly being that you need to type this stuff twice, so I am unsure whether this is feasable in your set up):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
  \text{beginning} \land
  \begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth-\widthof{$\text{beginning} \land$}]
   (\text{extremely long and boring junk occupying lots of space}) \\
   [\text{a variable substitution in brackets}]
 \end{multlined}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]